# Ext.define confusion

Tags: extjs

I'm having an issue which makes me think I might be misinterpreting the use of the ExtJS class architecture a bit. Herewith an example of a simplified version which demonstrates the issue

```
        Ext.define('Person', {
            name : 'Default',
            inventory : [],
            addInventoryItem : function(item) {
                Ext.Array.push(this.inventory, item);
            },
            inventoryList : function() {
                console.log("Inventory: " + JSON.stringify(this.inventory));
            },
            setName : function(name) {
                this.name = "name";
            }
        });

        Ext.define('Student', {
            extend : 'Person'
        });

        alex = Ext.create('Student');
        alex.setName("Alex");
        alex.addInventoryItem("Knifes");
        alex.inventoryList();

        david = Ext.create('Student');
        david.setName("David");
        david.addInventoryItem("Forks");
        david.inventoryList();
```

Output:

```
Inventory: ["Knifes"]
Inventory: ["Knifes","Forks"]
```

Expected Output:

```
Inventory: ["Knifes"]
Inventory: ["Forks"]
```

I would've expected the actual result in the event of overriding the class, but fail to understand why my second instance affects the superclass, and in turn reflects changes made by my first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is a single `inventory` array shared between all instances of your class. The array is created once at the time the class is defined, then each instance just gets a reference to that one array.

Basically you need to give each `Person` instance its own inventory array on creation, like this:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
  ...
  constructor: function() {
    this.inventory = [];
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: +1 but be careful using constructor when extending predefined extjs components (like a Panel for example). To add properties and behavior to extended components it is recommended to use initComponent method rather than constructor.

Comment: Thanks Rob and dbrin, that's the money shot right there :)

Comment: I prefer a judicious `callParent(arguments)` in the constructor - that way I know the instance is properly initialized as soon as it is created